# Best way to vizualize data overlaps in R

Tags: r, grouping, visualization, data-visualization

If I have a set of objects of which some share certain discrete properties (e.g. A,B,C,D set to 1 or 0), how could I visualize the coverage and overlaps of these properties in the dataset?

e.g.

```
        id  A  B  C  D
    1   34  1  0  0  1
    2   56  1  1  1  1
    3   14  0  0  1  1
    4   90  0  0  1  0
```

I'm using R primarily, and have tried some of the Venn diagram plots packages but this is not really scalable past 5 dimensions.

Is there another visualization package that is better suited for this?

Comment: A `heatmap` might work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is probably not from your original purpose of visualizing the data set, but it may be a way to go: consider visualizing the pairwise distances between any two of the observations (rows). Since you have binary data, you could use any distance measure that is suitable for this data type, see, for example, a paper titled "A survey of binary similarity measures". After that, you may consider clustering based on the calculated distance measures, so that you'll have heatmaps and other visualization tools commonly used from hierarchical clustering results.

Comment: Thanks, those give me some good directions to go in. I was thinking perhaps something similar to gradient descent, but I don't need to make predictions on the model just need to collapse dimensions. Never tried a heatmap, should be a fun experience!

Comment: @JoeKir: You're welcome. Make sure to check out the `heatmap.2` function in the `gplots` R package, which is an enhanced version of the `heatmap` function in R.